# What does しに行く mean?

Tags: translation

The sentence

> 東京へなにしに行くの？

translates to

> What are you going to Tokyo for?

**Question:** How do we parse (and what is the meaning of) にしに行く? (I'm assuming なに is just 何).

**Attempt:** According to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/94242/what-does-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%AB-mean), the term "なにしに" is short for

> 何をしに来たんだ？

but that seems to collide with with なに and 行く already in the sentence?

Comment: The answer in the other question was addressing what was left unsaid in that specific context with the "..." after なにしに. You have an example that continues after なにしに, so there's no wondering what comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

masu stem + に行く is used to express going somewhere and doing something.

し in this case is stem of する so しに行く would be the most generic version of this expression but you can use pretty much any verb.

Like 飲みに行こうか "Shall we go for a drink?"